# Get custom day of month from Calendar

Tags: java, date

I want to get day of the month to actually subtract days from that field.

Note: The day is custom selected, like 2012-09-10

```
Date d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").parse("2012-10-24);

Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar csd= Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(d2);

csd.add(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);
```

> csd.add(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), -5)

The above would actually error out saying `IllegalArgumentException`, but prints the correct value when I sysout it

`calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` would not print the correct day that is in d2. I am confused if I am doing something wrong or this is not the right approach?

**UPDATE**

This is what I am having exactly in my code. I want any array of date range. Say the user had set the end Date to `"2012-8-20"` which is in `d2`. I want past 30 days worth of dates in an array, which the code doesn't work.

```
for(int count = 30; count >=1; count--) {
   Calendar csd = Calendar.getInstance();
   csd.add(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -count);
   String dt = (csd.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + "-" + (csd.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + (csd.get(Calendar.DATE));
   aDays[30 - count] = dt;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit to provide a runnable example that illustrates the problem, with sample input and expected output? Where/how is `calendarEndDate` defined? Why are you creating two different calendars? Why is `d1` relevant?

Comment: @DNA. I just copied the code. I am not using d1 in this case, but I have it in my code for other purpose.

Comment: csd.add(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), -5); Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH is not a valid argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work for me.

```
        Date d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").parse((String)"2012-10-24");

        Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar csd= Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(d2);
        calendar.add(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);        
        System.out.println(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
        csd.add(csd.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);      
        System.out.println(new Date(csd.getTimeInMillis()));    


csd.add(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), -5);//wrong is giving an invalid argument
```

UPDATE

```
        String[] aDays = new String[30];
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd");
        for (int count = 30; count >= 1; count--) {
            Calendar csd = Calendar.getInstance();
            csd.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -count);
            aDays[30 - count] = (sdf.format(new Date(csd.getTimeInMillis())));      
        }

        //to double check it
        for (int count = 30; count >= 1; count--) {
            System.out.println(aDays[30 - count]);
        }
```

I hope you have all you need to understand how this works, good luck mate!

Comment: add csd.setTime(d2) if you want to set the date

Answer (score 2):

```
csd.add(calendarEndDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), -5)
```

First parameter should be type of field.

Example:

```
csd.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5)
```

In your case:

```
calendarEndDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

returns the day of month, but `Calendar` expects there which filed need to be modified.

Please refer calendar API [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

**EDIT:**

```
calendar.add(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);
int dayofMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println(dayofMont);
```

Comment: `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` would print a wrong value. I set the date as 2012-10-22 and it prints value 5 when I tried to sysout it

Comment: Can you help me to get right answer when a custom date is selected or what changes  I need to make in the code ?

Comment: Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH is constant which indicates which field you want to get or set in calendar. To get day of month, you write: csd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH). If you want to subtract 5 days, you write csd.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);

Comment: like @Nambari said, use calendarEndDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH). DAY_OF_MONTH is final static field in Calendar which will always return 5 . follow http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH  for detail

Comment: @user525146: I think you are unnecessarily working with two calendar objects.

Comment: @Nambari I want that date value because, I need to store dates in hashmap based on the date range submitted by the user. Printing would not suffice for me.

Comment: It is already in dayofMonth, isn't it? I just printed dayofMonth.